# Keep getting socket hang out on ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, node-modules, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am new to ElasticSearch.I am reindexing some indexes in my ElasticSearch Cluster. While I am trying to reindex an index that has a large amount of data I am getting Socket hang up error.

```
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
const tempclient = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: clusterhost,
  log: [{
    type: 'stdio',
    levels: ['error'],
  }],
  maxRetries: 50,
  requestTimeout: 1000 * 60 * 120,
  keepAliveFreeSocketTimeout: 1000 * 60 * 120,
});
await tempclient.reindex({
   body: {
      source: {
         index: indexes[i].index,
       },
      dest: {
         index: `logs-${yearMonth[0]}`,
      },
      script: {
         source: "ctx._type = 'doc';",
      },
  },
  timeout: '120m',
});
```

Comment: Try to set requestTimeout to 0

Comment: I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you finally find out where the error was coming from? Do you remember how to solve it?

Comment: Have the same error